# CakePHP 3.2 default redirect to the controllers' main pages

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-3.2

How can I specify the default pages (one page for every controller) in CakePHP 3.2 so that the cake will automatically redirect user to the page:

```
www.mypage/controller_name/action_name
```

if the user set in his browser the following url:

```
www.mypage/controller_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` action will be the landing page by default.  If you want to specify a different action as the default, you can add this to `routes.php`

```
Router::connect('/', ['controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'action_name']);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#quick-tour